# Scoping styles effect to blocks and elements in BEM

Tags: html, css, bem

From [BEM documentation](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) I can read that

> blocks can be nested

I understand that `Blocks` should be though of as reusable components with some inner structure created from `Elements` making them in some sense isolated, but what to do if I have e.g. `Button` `Block` that I need to use with `Text` `Block` inside. `Text` block doesn't declare color (this is simple example to illustrate my point, but can be any CSS property) and thus is effected by `Button`:

```
<div class="button">
  <div class="button__body">
    <div class="text">
      <span class="text__icon">
        
      </span>
      <span class="text__body">
        Hello
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
.button {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: orange;
}
.button__body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {}
.text__icon {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.text__body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

**Question: How BEM handles CSS effects on nested blocks?**

Should all elements have some kind of `normalize.css` applied to them as base, as we don't know where `Block`s would be used in the future and how they would behave.

Answer (score 1):

> Should all elements have some kind of `normalize.css` applied to them as base, as we don't know where Blocks would be used in the future and how they would behave.

You could, but it is more effective to trust parents than to distrust them. So, in general, you should avoid to use inherited properties (`font-size`, `font-weight`, `color`) on DOM elements that are ancestor of other blocks. Except for blocks which you really decide to work this way, of course.